# Start command in batch not accepting a window title when process is not on the path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been using the "Start" command in windows batch files and have come across a very odd situation, which is breaking some tests. Specifically, if an application is not on the PATH, when trying to invoke it through the start command the window title parameter seems to be ignored.

This seems to be reproducable on Windows 7 and 8 (and probably more) by doing the following:

- Start a new command prompt
- Run `start "testing" /d"C:\Windows\system32" chkdsk.exe`
- Observe the popup window has the given window title
- Do `SET PATH=` to destroy the path
- Run the Start command again, and observe that the new window does not have the correct window title.

I'm fortunately able to work around this problem in my testing, simply by appending the directory to the path, but what I would like to know is: Why is this happening?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For finding an obscure bug +1!

Comment: I think the inline documentation for `start` is wrong.  I've encountered this before.  Putting the title *after* the switches restores the behavior as expected.  `start /d "C:\Windows\System32" "testing" chkdsk.exe` results in `chkdsk` running in a spawned console window with the title "testing".

Comment: @rojo No it doesn't. I've just tested it. "do `SET PATH=` to destroy the path". Then try the command and you will see the bug. It doesn't matter if the title is after the switches.